# Getting a NullPointerException error while creating a linked list with a txt file

Tags: java, linked-list

Hello I am trying to create a link list using a txt file. I when I try to print the link list I created. I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "PlanetLinkedList.printLL()" because "<local3>" is null
    at test.main(test.java:12)
```

I do not know why I am getting this error, I double checked my method and I don't see anything wrong with it. Here is the main

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    // You are not allowed to change the main method.
    
    String inputfilename = "input.txt";    
    String outputfilename= "output.txt";
    PlanetLinkedList solarSystem = constructLLFromFile(inputfilename);
    
    solarSystem.printLL();
    
    System.out.println();
    
  }
  
static PlanetLinkedList constructLLFromFile(String theInputFile){
    System.out.println("Constructing the linked list from "+theInputFile);
    PlanetLinkedList head = null;
    try{
      File file = new File(theInputFile);
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
      int data = 0;
      head = new PlanetLinkedList("", 0, data); 
      int index = 0;
      while(scan.hasNext()){
        data = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        long  diamater = Long.parseLong(scan.nextLine());
        int moons  = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        Planet insertee = new Planet(name,diamater,moons);
        head.insert(insertee,index);
        index++;
      }
    }catch(Exception eee){
        
    }

    
    return null;    // cannot change

  }
}
```

Here is the link list

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

class PlanetLinkedList{
 private Planet head;
 
 PlanetLinkedList(){    
 }
 
 PlanetLinkedList(Planet initial){
   head=initial;
 }
 
 PlanetLinkedList(String n, long d, int m){
   head = new Planet(n, d, m);
 }
}
```

Here is the object class

```
class Planet{
  private String name;
  private long diameter;
  private int moon;
  
  Planet next;
  
  Planet(String n, long d, int m){    
    name = n;
    diameter = d;
    moon = m;
  }
  
  
  String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  
  long getDiameter(){
    return diameter;
  }
  
  int getMoon(){
    return moon;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+name+
           "\nDiameter: "+diameter+
           "\nMoon: "+moon;
  }
}
```

Just note I can't change the object or link list, only the method creating the link list.
Here is the txt file

```
Mercury
4879
0
Venus
12104
0
Earth
12756
1
Mars
6805
2
Saturn
120536
62
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`constructLLFromFile()` is returning `null` and you are doing `solarSystem.printLL();` after returning the value, this is raising the NPE.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // You are not allowed to change the main method.
    
    String inputfilename = "input.txt";    
    String outputfilename= "output.txt";
    PlanetLinkedList solarSystem = new PlanetLinkedList("", 0, data);
    constructLLFromFile(inputfilename, solarSystem);
    
    solarSystem.printLL();
    
    System.out.println();
    
  }
  
static PlanetLinkedList constructLLFromFile(String theInputFile, PlanetLinkedList solarSystem){
    System.out.println("Constructing the linked list from "+theInputFile);
    PlanetLinkedList head = null;
    try{
      File file = new File(theInputFile);
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
      int data = 0;
      int index = 0;
      while(scan.hasNext()){
        data = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        long  diamater = Long.parseLong(scan.nextLine());
        int moons  = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        Planet insertee = new Planet(name,diamater,moons);
        solarSystem.insert(insertee,index);
        index++;
      }
    }catch(Exception eee){
        
    }

    
    return null;    // cannot change

  }
```

By sending the `solarSystem` variable to the method, you don't need to worry by returning null. The above definition of the method will change the value of the variable and then print it.